# Adding facebook link to webpage

Tags: facebook, icons, html

Hi please excuse my ignorance as this is all new to me (you know, the teaching old dogs new tricks thing)..Ive just setting up a website and I want to put a link to my facebook page on it but I cant quite get my head around how to do it...please help a confused old girl...thanks

Comment: why do you mean by "put a link"? `<a href="..."`?

Answer (score 2):

You must use HTML:

```
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=your_facebook_id">My facebook page</a>
```

You can obtain help finding your FB ID here http://www.ehow.com/how_5753004_facebook-id.html It's very easy.

---

If you really have no idea about what I am talking about, give us your shining new website address and we can continue.

Answer (score 0):

1) Go to the facebook.com/badges website.

2) Log in to your Facebook account.

3) Click on the type of badge you want to create.  The Profile badge will allow you to list details that appear on your profile's information page such as name, email, birthday and hometown. You can also choose to display your status updates and recent photos using this option. The Like badge allows you to display a specific business or organization that you like. The Photo badge displays a thumbnail collection of photos you posted to your account. The Badge, Profile and Like options are available to pages or profiles (business or personal). The Page badge is available only to people who have created Pages for a business or organization. The Page badge gives website viewers the ability to click and Like your page while still on your website.

4) Select the customization features related to the badge type you are creating. For the Profile badge, click the "Edit this Badge" link and select the check boxes for the information you want to include. Click the "Save" button. Click the type of Web page you have. Facebook will provide custom code for a Blogger or Typepad blog. If you have a different type of website click the "Other" button. Copy the code provided and paste into your website. For the Like badge, select the page you want to display from the drop-down menu. Then copy the code provided and paste into your website. For the Photo badge, select the radio button for the layout option and choose the number of photos you want to display from the drop-down menu. Click the "Save" button. Click the type of website you have. Copy the code provided and paste into your website. For the Pages badge, click "Edit this Badge" and select the layout type and the items you want to display. Click the "Save" button. Click the button for the type of website you have, and copy and paste the code into your website.